# Closing a jdbc connection object when session expires

Tags: java, jdbc

I am creating a Connection object and making jdbc connection in a constructor of a class (DbTest).

Then in another java class(RequestFilter.java), I am initializing this object and storing this instance object in HTTP Session,

```
DbTest dbtest = new DbTest();
session.setAttribute("dbtest", dbtest);
```

My question is, is there a way to close the connection object that was created when the session expires? Or will it automatically get closed when it expires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and within [`sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) method do the cleanup. However your architecture worries me. You should not store raw JDBC connection in HTTP session!

- you cannot migrate the HTTP session to another server
- You can easily create thousands of open database connections, HTTP sessions are much more lightweight
- 99.9% of the time your database connections are idle
- you aren't probably handling connection timeouts and other failures

Any reasons to have a connection per user rather than a connection pool?

Comment: I see. Plz see my question in elaborate in the following link since I was not able to add enough in comments section in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723270/making-jdbc-connection-and-storing-in-session

Answer (score 0):

You could implement HttpSessionBindingListener.

Comment: `HttpSessionBindingListener`: *Causes an object to be notified when it is bound to or unbound from a session*. OP wants to be notified *when the session expires*. `HttpSessionListener` is a better choice.

Comment: Causes an object to be notified when it is bound to or unbound from a session. The object is notified by an HttpSessionBindingEvent object. This may be as a result of a servlet programmer explicitly unbinding an attribute from a session, due to a session being invalidated, or due to a session timing out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly close connection object. You can close collection in finalize method but it is not recommended as finalize may not get called. Better approach is to write and call method  which will explicitly close this connection. Creating JDBC connection in constructor is also not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

managing a connection pool, may also be an issue. To get a connection from a connection pool you need to use synchronization, which is preventing other threads (clients) to access the connection pool.